# Does apple sign macOS as they do it for iOS

Tags: macos, ios, mojave

As we know Mojave 10.14.3 is already released but 6gb non pausable download is not possible due to network issues I’m having, so I’m trying to install the initial mojave 10.14(18A391) downloading through torrent or other trusted sites and then update to 10.14.3

My doubt is

can i install 10.14 now?

Is apple still signing 10.14(18A391) like they do for iOS?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) It is generally not-recommended to download critical software such as OS updates via torrents. Recommended to download from official sources such as Mac App Store or via online recovery.

Comment: Mojave is a free download and update. If you have a Mac from 2011 or later, your Mac will be able to boot to recovery mode and you will be able to install the update there, or can do the same from the App Store.  If on the other hand you have built yourself a "Hackintosh", then you can upgrade from Snow Leopard if you have been able to install it off the DVD, which is available from the online store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update process on macOS and iOS is very different.

Apple does not sign macOS installers/updates individually for each device. This means that there is no requirement that Apple "still signs" these updates for them to work and be installable.

This means that as long as you have an valid upgrade that at some point worked, it will always work in the future (you might have to set your computers clock back if the upgrade file is several years old though).

In general you should be very careful when downloading upgrades from a different source than Apple itself. Never install the upgrade without confirming that the file is identical to the original Apple file. This is commonly done by taking an MD5 checksum of the file, and comparing it to the known good checksum.

You can find the MD5 checksum of a file by running the following command in the Terminal:

```
md5 filename
```

where you replace "filename" with the actual name of the file, you want to checksum.

The md5 checksum looks something like this: ecfcaab9ad3d019ee982abdc84eff102 (just an example)